# How to sort a list of strings in terms of a duplicate re-ordered copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Take these two list of strings for example.

```
names = ['Jack', 'Steve', 'Marc', 'Xavier', 'Bob']
names_copy = ['Steve', 'Marc', 'Xavier', 'Bob', 'Jack']
```

Essentially I'm trying to find a way to sort `names_copy` in the same way that `names` is sorted.

So, a sorted version of `names_copy` would result in `['Jack', 'Steve', 'Marc', 'Xavier', 'Bob']`

> NOTE: in my program, names_copy is being created with a map, so I cannot use `.sort()`, `sorted()` works however.

I understand the sorted() function takes in a key parameter indicating the sort order, but I'm not too sure how to use it here.

Comment: You might need to explain the algorithm that determines the order of the strings. It's certainly not lexical

Comment: From your question I understand that you want 'names_copy' in same order as 'names'. And names list itself is not in a lexical. So you can do one thing by create a dict by making Strings as a key and index as a value For example: {'jack': 0}. Now you can check the string in names_copy with dict keys and place the string in names_copy with index you got from dict. Hope this helps.